# Change the size of SVG according to device size in D3.js?

Tags: html, d3.js, leaflet, dc.leaflet.js

I am trying to visualize map and charts using leaflet.js and d3.js. I want to make the view device compatible. But my charts and maps are not device compatible. The code of showing a simple bar chart is below:

```
function updateCharts(data){

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 250 - margin.top;
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([ 0, width ], .05);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([ height, 0 ]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(20);

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.time; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.speed1; })]);

var svg=d3.select("#bar").append("svg").attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g").attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var transition = svg.transition().duration(750), delay = function(d, i) {
    return i * 50;
};
svg.append("text").attr("x", width / 2).attr("y", 0).style("text-anchor",
        "middle").text("Speed of Lane1 Vs Time");

//Create X axis label   
svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", width / 2 )
    .attr("y",  height + margin.bottom)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Time");

svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 0-margin.left)
    .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
    .attr("dy", "1em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Speed");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", "-.55em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .attr("x",5)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle");

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect").transition().delay(0)
    .style("fill", "red")
    .attr("x", function(d,i) { return x(d.time); }) //v
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.speed1); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.speed1); }); 
//function(d){return " "+d.datetime;}

//transition.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

// New SVG
}
```

In the html I also added meta tag for device compatibility like below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Even if the deveice size is small there appears horizontal Scrollbar. But i don't want to see such scrollbar horizontally. I want the charts and maps to be fitted within the device width. Can anyone kindly help me to solve this?

Comment: Use e.g. `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` for determining the dimensions of the SVG.

Answer (score -1):

Example (note: uses jQuery):

```
var $graphic = $('#graphic');
function drawGraphic() {
    var margin = { top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 30 };
    var width = $graphic.width() - margin.left - margin.right;
    $graphic.empty();
    // ... code to create the chart ...
}
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {  //loading data, may differ
    // ... manipulate data here ...
    drawGraphic();
    window.onresize = drawGraphic;
}
```

A method based on D3 responsive charts described here: http://blog.apps.npr.org/2014/05/19/responsive-charts.html

My example is described here: http://bl.ocks.org/michalskop/2fa7d4c0ae029c36ba4e

See it in action here: http://bl.ocks.org/michalskop/raw/2fa7d4c0ae029c36ba4e/

My demo for Leaflet based responsive map: http://bl.ocks.org/michalskop/raw/001f6182db52d08f4925/